# Ionic 2 is loading the stale component

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my footer component.  I am calling few pages from the footer bar as follows.  When i click on the footer, it is loading the stale component. i debugged it and found out it is not calling the constructor of the component (where i have the loading logic to refresh the data). i have to click twice from the footer to call the component to get the correct data

```
tab-footer.component.html

  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="home" tabIcon="md-home" 
   [rootParams]="homeparams"></ion-tab>
     <ion-tab [root]="alertsPage" tabIcon="md-notifications-outline">
    </iontab>
   <ion-tab [root]="flagged" tabIcon="flag"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>


  @Component({
   selector: 'app-tab-footer',
   templateUrl: './tab-footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab-footer.component.scss']
  })
  export class TabFooterComponent {

  home = HomeComponent;
  alertsPage = AlertsComponent;
  flagged = FlaggedComponent;
  homeparams: any;

  constructor(public navparam: NavParams) {
    this.homeparams = navparam;
   }

 }
```

Here is my one of the components that is called from footer

```
  @Component({
 selector: 'app-flagged',
 templateUrl: './flagged.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flagged.component.scss']
})
export class FlaggedComponent {

    someData1: any;
    someData:any[] = [];

    someObj = {}

 constructor(public someService: SomeServiceService,
     public exampleService: ExampleService,
     public navParams: NavParams,
     public navCtrl: NavController) {

   // some loading logic
   }
```

Can anyone help finding out why it is not calling constructor every time?
Do I have specify some property to load it fresh?
Thank you

Comment: How is the navigation triggered by the TabFooterComponent?

Comment: This is not enough information to reproduce your issue. Can you either include a complete minimal example or event better a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: sure. i will include

Comment: I updated the question with navigation trigger @nipuna777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the lifecycle event `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewWillEnter` to your `FlaggedComponent` class and move your update or loading logic from the constructor into one of those methods.

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
  console.log('the page has entered');
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  console.log('the page is about to enter');
}
```

> **ionViewDidEnter** is called when the page has fully entered and is now the active page.
> This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.
>
> **ionViewWillEnter** is called when the page is about to enter and become the active page.

reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events